# Sum of Arrays and Pointers with Functions

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have 2 arrays. I read them trough a function. Then I sum them trough another function and print the sum array trough another function. I have to use pointers all the time. Problem is, it prints the sum of the last two elements of the array as the whole sum array. How can I fix this?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void read(int *pdato);
void print(int *pdato);
void sum(int *pdato1,int *pdato2, int *pdato);

int main(){
    int A[5],B[5],C[5],i;
    printf("Data for first array:\n");
    read(A);
    printf("Data for the second array\n");
    read(B);
    sum(A,B,C);
    printf("Result:\n");
    print(C);
    return 0;
}
void read(int *pdato){
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<5;i++){
   printf("[%d]:",i);
   scanf("%d",pdato);
}

}

void sum(int *A,int *B, int *C){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
            *(C+i)=*(A+i)+*(B+i);
    }
}

void print(int *pdato){
int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    printf("[%d]:%d\n",i,*pdato);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be `scanf("%d",&pdato[i]);` in `read`.

Comment: Use array notation in `sum`.  It's clearer: `C[i] = A[i] + B[i];`.

Comment: Should be `printf("[%d]:%d\n",i,pdato[i]);` in `print`.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Thanks, added your comment about scanf to my answer.

Comment: Don't use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants)!

Comment: I am not allowed to use array notation. :(

Comment: What kind of sick constraint is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building off of @Massey101, here is the answer without using array notation:

Should be

```
printf("[%d]:%d\n",i,*(pdato + i));
```

and

```
scanf("%d",pdato + i);
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be

```
printf("[%d]:%d\n",i,pdato[i]);
```

and

```
scanf("%d",&pdato[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not allowed to use array notation. Has to be pointers only

Comment: The answer is correct. You just have to convert array notation to pointer notation.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is below.
 Increment pointer after every data read to point to correct memory location to store inputs.

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
    scanf("%d",pdato);
    pdato++;
}
```

Increment pointer while printing results, so that it will fetch results from correct memory location as show below

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++) {    
    printf("[%d]:%d\n",i,*pdato);
    pdato++;
}
```